# SQL Duplicate entry for key 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I've recently had to take over the management of a database (within a school) that records certain stats, at the start of each year these stats are supposed to be reset.

I've been given a piece of code to run to reset these stats, however it is throwing out a **'Duplicate entry '10172-0' for key 1** error when I try to run it. (the '10172-0' part also happens on various other numbers/student_id's). The code I've been given is:

```
Insert into cfc.student_stats (students_id, no_cfcs)
Select student_id, 0
from roombookings.students
where student_id >= 1
and student_id <= 15635
```

I've checked and there aren't duplicate entries when I check out the various student_id's so I'm at a loss with what to do. Underneath the error message I get a button to 'Browse' which then tells me the following:

```
Error

SQL query: Documentation

SELECT *
FROM
WHERE CONCAT_WS( "-", students_id, no_cfcs ) = "10172-0"
ORDER BY students_id, no_cfcs

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CONCAT_WS("-", students_id,  no_cfcs)
                    = "10172-0"' at line 3
```

I've had a browse through lots of other similar problems on here but none of them seemed to match up with what I was getting (but I don't really understand SQL). Any help appreciated, cheers!

Comment: are you missing table name in query or its is just typo..?

Comment: The way it is all set up 'cfc' is a database, and 'student_stats' is the table within cfc.

'roombookings' is also a database and 'students' is a table within that.

Hope this helps - not overly familiar with SQL and this has been dropped on me last minute.

Comment: Yeah we got that...but as i told in answer are you adding table name inside query

Comment: see my edited answer you are missing adding table name in query

Comment: But in the code I am running it is doing `FROM roombookings.students` after `Select student_id, 0` ?

Comment: i am saying about `WHERE CONCAT_WS( "-", students_id, no_cfcs ) = "10172-0"` this query

Comment: I think I'm confused as I am not running that query, I run the first query, get the duplicate entry error with a button underneath it saying browse. If I click the browse button it then takes me to another page saying error with that error message, but I haven't actually inputted that query.

Comment: remove `0` from select query and try `Select student_id
from roombookings.students`

Comment: That gives me a `MySQL said: Documentation
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 `

Comment: paste entire page code....because i think some other query is not working

Comment: `Error

SQL query: Documentation

INSERT INTO cfc.student_stats(
students_id,
no_cfcs
)
SELECT student_id
FROM roombookings.students
WHERE student_id >=1
AND student_id <=15635

MySQL said: Documentation
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 `

Comment: now tell me what you want to do..??? insert data..???

Comment: In the cfc table I want to reset the student_stats to 0 for all of the students. student_stats has two fields 'students_id' and 'no_cfcs' so say Student A with the id 10123 had 152 cfc's I want this to show 0.

Comment: no...if i give you any other solution i might lead you astray because i do not know what exactly you are doing...i provided all the possible solution for which you have described in comment and question

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this

```
SELECT *
FROM
WHERE
```

in above query you missed to add table name.

**Edit**

```
SELECT *
FROM
   roombookings.students
WHERE
```

Comment: -1 I bet that's just a typo, the query won't run altogether if the table name isn't set in the FROM clause

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood the OP question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding that second error, I'm not sure why you don't just use:

```
WHERE students_id = 10172 AND no_cfcs = 0
```

It seems a bit silly and inefficient to turn them into strings just to compare them.

In addition, it appears you haven't selected an actual table to read from, so something like this would be better:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      cfc.student_stats
WHERE     students_id = 10172
AND       no_cfcs = 0
```

There's also no point ordering by `students_id, no_cfcs` when you're only allowing one possibility for each, so I removed that bit.

---

Regarding your *first* error, I suspect that *may* be because of duplicate entries in the `roombookings.students` table. If you do:

```
select student_id, count(*)
from roombooking.students
where student_id >= 1 and student_id <= 15635
group by student_id
```

and the second column has any number greater than one in it, you'll get an error trying to insert duplicates into the `cfc.student_stats` table.

That's because for *each* student_id in that `roombooking.students` table, you'll try to create one in the `cfc.student_stats` table with a primary key made up of the student ID and the constant `0`.

If you *don't* get any counts greater than one, then it's most likely that there's *already* a row in the `cfc.student_stats` table with that student ID.

Comment: OP missing table name in query

Comment: I smell tactical downvoting. +1 to balance.

Comment: _I_ smell bacon, I'm off to the kitchen, back in a minute :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help - in regards to the first error I have ran the query you gave but none of the results have a count greater than 1.